# ReactJs Node - Webpack sass-loader jpg 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack, sass-loader

I'm really getting crazy.
I'm working on a `React/Node+Express` app, but I'd never been imagined that a so simple action like load an image from `sass` would be so terribly complicated.

In my root I have `main.jsx`, `index.html` and 2 folders: "`public`" (that includes `css/js/img`) and "`components`" that contains `header.jsx` and others.
Now, I want to load a background image in my `header.jsx` component

**header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
require('../public/css/header.scss')

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <header></header>
    }
}
```

To do this I've configured mywebpack to load sass:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: './public/js/build/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]" 
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/css/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Then, my `header.scss`

**header.scss**

```
header {
    background-image: url('/public/img/header-bg.jpg');
}
```

To load static files from my Node server I've configured my folder:

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

In my `console` I get this error: `http://localhost:3000/public/img/header-bg.jpg 404 (Not Found)`. I really can't understand what's wrong with this so basic configuration.